# Как подключиться к myGPT по API?

Tags: python, api, chatgpt

Имеется настроенная роль в myGPT .

[image: Картинка)]

Вот как к ней подключиться по API?

Comment: На данный момент кастомные ГПТ не поддерживают АПИ. Максимум, что можно сделать, так это создать первое системное сообщение и там указать инструкции, не более того.